# Query change to single column temporal table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server temporal table with the following data:

```
ID  ValidFrom       ValidTo         MyValue
23  7/7/19 13:51    7/7/19 13:51    0
23  7/7/19 13:51    9/9/19 11:22    0
23  9/9/19 11:22    9/9/19 11:23    0
23  9/9/19 11:23    5/14/20 23:02   0
23  5/14/20 23:02   5/16/20 20:02   0
23  5/16/20 20:02   5/16/20 23:53   0
23  5/16/20 23:53   5/16/20 23:58   0
23  5/16/20 23:58   5/16/20 23:58   0
23  5/16/20 23:58   5/16/20 23:59   0
23  5/16/20 23:59   5/17/20 0:16    0
23  5/17/20 0:16    5/17/20 1:47    0
23  5/17/20 1:47    5/17/20 1:48    0
23  5/17/20 1:48    5/20/20 16:52   0
23  5/20/20 16:52   5/20/20 16:52   0
23  5/20/20 16:52   8/22/20 0:22    0
23  8/22/20 0:22    9/3/20 20:22    0
23  9/3/20 20:22    9/3/20 20:23    0
23  9/3/20 20:23    12/31/99 0:00   6
```

I want to perform a query so I only get the point of change of the 'MyValue', like so:

```
23  7/7/19 13:51    7/7/19 13:51    0
23  9/3/20 20:23    12/31/99 0:00   6


SELECT ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue FROM MyTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL WHERE ID = 23
```

Gets me the values, but how do I arrive at my desired two-column result?

The following proposed solution does NOT work:

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT ID, ValidFrom, MyValue,
    LAG(MyValue, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ValidFrom) prevVal,
    LEAD(MyValue, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ValidFrom) nextVal
    FROM MyTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL WHERE ID = 23
)
SELECT ID, ValidFrom, MyValue
FROM data
WHERE (prevVal IS NOT NULL AND prevVal <> MyValue) OR
(nextVal IS NOT NULL AND nextVal <> MyValue)
ORDER BY ValidFrom DESC;
```

Resulting in the following results:

```
ID  ValidFrom   MyValue
23  2020-09-03 20:23:32.23  6
23  2020-09-03 20:22:00.41  0
```

Comment: I see that you have changed your question and now returning a logically incorrect result based on your question. Then Aaron Bertrand's would be right.

Comment: I added another answer, matching your edited question. You were in fact asking for first occurences of MyValue, not where the change occurs as you said in your original post. Then it is a very simple group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.x(ID int, ValidFrom datetime, ValidTo datetime, MyValue tinyint);

INSERT dbo.x VALUES -- notice I inserted the first two rows in a different order
(23  ,'7/7/19 13:51','9/9/19 11:22',    0),
(23  ,'7/7/19 13:51','7/7/19 13:51',    0),
(23  ,'9/9/19 11:22','9/9/19 11:23',    0),
(23  ,'9/9/19 11:23','5/14/20 23:02',   0),
(23  ,'9/3/20 20:22','9/3/20 20:23',    0),
(23  ,'9/3/20 20:23','12/31/99 0:00',   6);
```

With the WHERE clause limiting the results to ID = 23, you don't need PARTITION BY, but you will need to add it back if you ever pull back more than one ID. Ordering by ID when you are only pulling back one single value for ID makes zero sense. Here are three approaches, the first two being overly illustrative of the sequence (showing how "is_anchor" is determined), and the last being the most concise:

1.With just lag:

```
;WITH cte1 AS 
(
  SELECT ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue, 
    prev = LAG(MyValue, 1) OVER (/* PARTITION BY ID */ ORDER BY ValidFrom, ValidTo) 
  FROM dbo.x WHERE ID = 23 --MyTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL WHERE ID = 23
),
cte2 AS (
SELECT ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue, is_anchor = 
   CASE WHEN prev <> MyValue or prev IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   FROM cte1
)
SELECT ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue
FROM cte2 WHERE is_anchor = 1
ORDER BY ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo;
```

2.With row_number:

```
;WITH cte1 AS 
(
  SELECT ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue, 
    prev = LAG(MyValue, 1) OVER (/* PARTITION BY ID */ ORDER BY ValidFrom, ValidTo),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (/* PARTITION BY ID */ ORDER BY ValidFrom, ValidTo)
  FROM dbo.x WHERE ID = 23 --MyTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL WHERE ID = 23
),
cte2 AS (
SELECT ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue, is_anchor = 
   CASE WHEN prev <> MyValue OR rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   FROM cte1 
)
SELECT ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue
FROM cte2 WHERE is_anchor = 1
ORDER BY ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo;
```

3.With one less CTE (woop!):

```
;WITH cte1 AS 
(
  SELECT ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue, 
    prev = LAG(MyValue, 1) OVER (/* PARTITION BY ID */ ORDER BY ValidFrom, ValidTo) 
  FROM dbo.x WHERE ID = 23 --MyTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL WHERE ID = 23
)
SELECT ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue
   FROM cte1 WHERE prev <> MyValue or prev IS NULL
  ORDER BY ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo;
```

In all three cases, the results are:

```
ID  ValidFrom            ValidTo              MyValue
==  ===================  ===================  =======
23  2019-07-07 13:51:00  2019-07-07 13:51:00  0
23  2020-09-03 20:23:00  1999-12-31 00:00:00  6
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4a7e5bacf7090d5b8773ae1de0d33364)

Comment: Thanks, Aaron, this is really neat! Amazing how complex this is to pull off. I did have an overflow issue with your query since 'MyValue' is a tinyint, although converting it to int did the trick.. I guess LAG and LEAD always return int? What if MyValue was a varchar() type? Not asking you to write more queries, but just comment on the data type issue.

Comment: @user1054922 I had no idea your source table had a `tinyint`, this is why we like to see source tables and sample data as I have shown here, create table, insert, even a fiddle, this makes it much easier to help you and not have to make assumptions about your data. The overflow is because I assumed `int` and used a token value of something that definitely isn't going to fit in a tinyint. You could use 255 in its place, if no value could ever be 255, or you could stick with your cast, or you could pay the price of an additional row_number like in the second answer.

Comment: @user1054922 If MyValue wasn't numeric, then you would just use some kind of string comparison to determine a difference. Instead of `prev-MyValue <> 0`, for example, you would say `prev <> MyValue`, which actually would also work for numeric values, I was just overthinking it. [Redid the fiddle to show this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ac47289142e9e1fcf475549d6f9da0e) (but still with numerics).

Comment: Got it. This has been a good learning experience. I'll also be sure to structure my question in the future as you described. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use lag() function. ie:

```
with data as
(
 SELECT ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue, 
   lag(MyValue,1)  over (/*Partition by id*/ order by validFrom), prevVal
   lead(MyValue,1)  over (/*Partition by id*/ order by validFrom) nextVal
  FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 23
)
select ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue
from data
where (prevVal is not null and prevVal <> myValue) OR
(nextVal is not null and nextVal <> myValue);
```

PS: Probably you would want to order by validFrom.

UPDATE: Edited to order by validFrom as in my suggestion and correcting that 'FOR SYSTEM_TIME', I have no idea where it came from.

Here is [DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=35f0c9a514360f71fe81f214c43ebe97)

UPDATE: I understood the question something different (where the change occurs - as it was in original question). But in reality what you were asking was very simply the first occurrences of MyValue:

```
select ID, min(validFrom) ValidFrom, min(validTo) validTo, MyValue
  from x
  where ID = 23
  group by x.ID,MyValue;
```

and here is [DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f94b75ed580e19ad21b9f02d2d2ea82a)

Comment: To be safe and deterministic, you probably want the order by inside the window functions to be on `ValidFrom, ValidTo`, not on `ID`.

Comment: Thanks! But if I change 'order by id' inside of each partition by, I get:

ID ValidFrom                 MyValue
23 2020-09-03 20:23:32.23 6
23 2020-09-03 20:22:00.41 0

whereas if I keep it as your original, the start date of July 7th, 2019 is in the correct place.

Comment: @AaronBertrand What I mean is that if I modify the query as you mentioned in the comment here, it gives me bad data. Cetin Basoz, Could you please modify your original answer to illustrate what you're talking about?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not saying your addition is incorrect... what I'm saying is that if I change PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID to PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY VALIDFROM, It does not give me the results that I expect from my original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220946/discussion-between-user1054922-and-aaron-bertrand).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I added that as a comment only, because those values that "look like" a datetime may not be really datetimes but varchars (I have seen people doing that).

Comment: `ValidFrom` still isn't enough... there are ties on that column _in this sample data_ which again lead to _potentially_ not picking the row you think you will. Try it with the rows inserted in a different order (like my answer showed) and you'll see that you don't get the row the OP wanted. Your second solution doesn't work because it doesn't handle the case where `MyValue` changes from 0 to 6 and then back to 0 again later. The OP expects a row for each change. This is an islands problem, not a "unique values across all rows" problem.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8db7e514db3fecba45d2070c1a9a3ccc

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Ok you could add validTo if you like to. But anyway it was really a simple group by and min() as in your dbfiddle. There is no melting, it returns the first occurences as OP asks.

Comment: "if you like to"? I don't understand, the demo shows it picks the wrong row if you don't. Also, I think you have reached the wrong conclusion about grouping. `2019-07-07 13:51 / 1999-12-31 00:00 / 0` is not a valid row in the source. The OP didn't ask for aggregation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, it doesn't mean he didn't ask for aggregation when he didn't clearly said that as "aggregation". In his edited question the result is simply asking for the first occurences of MyValue. Original question was asking the point of change.
I say if you like to because it is not a big deal to add and afterall what is needed was a simple aggregation.

Comment: /shrug ok, the desired results he showed in the question don’t give any hint about aggregation either, so I’m not sure where you’re getting that from.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work with this query.  To adapt to a system versioned table you would need to add FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL to the query.

Data

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.x(ID int, ValidFrom datetime, ValidTo datetime, MyValue int);

INSERT dbo.x VALUES -- notice I inserted the first two rows in a different order
(23  ,'7/7/19 13:51','7/7/19 13:51',    0),
(23  ,'7/7/19 13:51','9/9/19 11:22',    0),
(23  ,'9/9/19 11:22','9/9/19 11:23',    0),
(23  ,'9/9/19 11:23','5/14/20 23:02',   0),
(23  ,'5/14/20 23:02','5/16/20 20:02',  0),
(23  ,'5/16/20 20:02','5/16/20 23:53',   0),
(23  ,'5/16/20 23:53','5/16/20 23:58',   0),
(23  ,'5/16/20 23:58','5/16/20 23:58',   0),
(23  ,'5/16/20 23:58','5/16/20 23:59',   0),
(23  ,'5/16/20 23:59','5/17/20 0:16',   0),
(23  ,'5/17/20 0:16','5/17/20 1:47',    0),
(23  ,'5/17/20 1:47','5/17/20 1:48',    0),
(23  ,'5/17/20 1:48','5/20/20 16:52',   0),
(23  ,'5/20/20 16:52','5/20/20 16:52',   0),
(23  ,'5/20/20 16:52','8/22/20 0:22',    0),
(23  ,'8/22/20 0:22','9/3/20 20:22',    0),
(23  ,'9/3/20 20:22','9/3/20 20:23',    0),
(23  ,'9/3/20 20:23','12/31/99 0:00',   6);
```

Query

```
;with data_cte as
(
 SELECT ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue, 
   lag(MyValue, 1, -1)  over (Partition by id order by ValidFrom, ValidTo) prevVal
  FROM x  WHERE ID = 23
) 
select ID, ValidFrom, ValidTo, MyValue from data_cte 
where prevVal=-1
      OR prevVal <> myValue;
```

Results

```
ID  ValidFrom   ValidTo                              MyValue
23  2019-07-07 13:51:00.000 2019-07-07 13:51:00.000 0
23  2020-09-03 20:23:00.000 1999-12-31 00:00:00.000 6
```

Comment: On mobile so can’t check but in your results the second row is the wrong row and not the row the OP expects. Actually first row is the wrong row also.

Comment: Yea I see.  The first row in the data was not correct.  I edited in on your answer too to reflect the OP's data in the question.  There's a time part here we're not seeing too.  But to get the OP's result is just the ValidTo column of the query no?

Comment: I edited the order of the first two rows to demonstrate that `order by id` is naive and can't be relied upon. It makes the outcome nondeterministic because if all rows have the same id then there is no order. So lag/lead/prevval/nextval are nondeterministic. The answer should get the right rows regardless of what order the data was inserted in - it's about the data in the row, not when it was inserted. Did you try the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c9070d162b9c785857f171ea083a6e9)?

Comment: This still doesn't produce the right rows because ordering by id relies on the assumption that ordering by the OP's desired ordering will magically happen based on the insert order (and the lack of new indexes or updated stats or 20 other things that can influence nondeterministic order). [This is easy to reproduce with far fewer rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf78445ae2768443211d14d4e59dc53f).

Comment: You're right.  I updated it to make the ORDER BY ValidFrom, ValidTo.  Now it's the same as yours but I use the optional default value argument of the LAG function and I don't use ROW_NUMBER or 2 CTE's.  Anyway, nicely done Aaron :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't find 2 CTEs a problem, it can actually be very helpful to lay out for less experienced users how we get from the first CTE to the result. YMMV. Also I only added the ROW_NUMBER() variation when the OP revealed that MyValue was tinyint and so any magic value (whether in COALESCE or in LAG) may no longer be "as safe" to use as a comparison. `-1` will require an explicit conversion too, but I updated after that to avoid any magic numbers anyway.